# You must be authenticated to make requests - GoogleAuthenticator

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, google-api-dotnet-client

I am trying to upload videos using the .NET API on an Android Phone using Xamarin. I am unable to authenticate and I get the error in the subject line. Here is the code from Xamarin:

https://github.com/xamarin/google-apis/blob/master/src/Android/Google.Apis.Android/Apis/Authentication/GoogleAuthenticator.cs

I used HttpScoop and it appears there is no web traffic.

I am using the web application ID:

**Client ID for web applications**

Client ID:

***.apps.googleusercontent.com

Email address:

***@developer.gserviceaccount.com

Client secret:

-***

Redirect URIs:  http://jmawebtechnologies.com

JavaScript origins: http://jmawebtechnologies.com

Here is how I create the Google Authenticator:

```
GoogleAuthenticator Auth ()
{
return new Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.GoogleAuthenticator (ClientID, new Uri ("http://jmawebtechnologies.com"),                                                                      Google.Apis.Youtube.v3.YoutubeService.Scopes.YoutubeUpload.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Can you run fiddler or something similar that we can see the exact requests you send to the server?

Comment: I did run it. There appears to be no traffic. See my new request image.

Answer (score 0):

I found out I must call GetUI. This opens a browser window where the user logs into Google.

```
StartActivity(auth2.GetUI (this));

                    auth2.Completed += (sender, eventArgs) => {


                        if (eventArgs.IsAuthenticated) {
                            MakeAlert("Is auth", "Accepted!");
                        } else {
                            // The user cancelled
                            MakeAlert("Is not auth", "failure");
                        }
                    };
```

Comment: Hey, whre did you get auth2. Can you post auth2 code? Thanks